# Change image on radio checked using Jquery plugin Pikachoose

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, radio-button, gallery

Okay so I have radio buttons to choose the colour of the t-shirt design and an image gallery showing what these look like:

http://www.pazzle.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_1&products_id=3#.UHpHP00WK27

Note: The gallery currently scrolls through automatically, I can turn this off if needed.

This is the code that does the work:

```
<div id="pikawrapper">
  <div class="pikachoose"> 
    <?php if (sizeof($images_array) > 0) { ?> 
      <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika"> 
        <?php for($img=0; $img<sizeof($images_array); $img++) { 
                echo '<li>' . zen_image('images/' . $images_array[$img]) . '</li>'; 
              } ?> 
      </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essentially, the gallery is a Jquery slider called **[pikachoose](http://www.pikachoose.com/)** which pulls the images from an array. I upload the images in my content management area and the gallery does the work. **I'm wondering how difficult would it be to have the image gallery display the corresponding colour when chosen?**

Comment: **Without knowing what you've done, it's difficult to tell.** Even more so when **you don't state what language you need help with**: PHP / Javascript / etc. __Please clarify your question.__

Comment: I apologize, basically the gallery is a jquery slider called pikachoose which pulls the images from a PHP array. I upload the images in my content management area and the gallery does the work. I then set up product attributes in the form of radio buttons and styled them with CSS. I assume Javascript would be the best way to create a link between the gallery and the attribute options?

Comment: Not a problem. I edited your post to reflect your elucidation.

Comment: Anyone got any other suggestions?

Comment: Still having trouble with this, any way to do this for more effeciently?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it could be done...

```
var imgTranslate={9:3};
$('#productAttributes .wrapperAttribsOptions input').bind('click',function() {
   $('#pikame').data('pikachoose').GoTo(imgTranslate[this.value]);
});
```

You'd have to match up the color buttons with the images in the scrollie, like I have matched color 9 with the 3rd image.

Comment: This almost works beautifully. With your code, I can click option blue, it will go to blue but only as long as the image is next to the current image. In other words, it can't skip more than 1 image. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, how can this work for other t-shirts with a different colour range?